# Python: How to import package twice?

Tags: python, import, package

Is there a way to import a package twice in the same python session, under the same name, but at different scope, in a multi-threaded environment ?

I would like to import the package, then override some of its functions to change its behavior only when used in specific class.

For instance, is it possible to achieve something like this ?

```
import mod

class MyClass:

  mod = __import__('mod')

  def __init__():
     mod.function = new_function # override module function

  def method():
     mod.function() # call new_function

mod.function() # call original function
```

It might seem weird, but in this case the user deriving the class wouldn't have to change his code to use the improved package.

Comment: about this question, I remembered my program. it was like this: ``import filename ; print('import')``. So this program will **import/run itself**. I thought this will make a endless loop, but it only print ``import`` twice(so it only import itself once).

Comment: why do you need `mod = __import__('mod')` and not simply `mod = mod` ?

Answer (score 2):

To import a module as a copy:

```
def freshimport(name):
    import sys, importlib
    if name in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules[name]
    mod = importlib.import_module(name)
    sys.modules[name] = mod
    return mod
```

Test:

```
import mymodule as m1
m2 = freshimport('mymodule')
assert m1.func is not m2.func
```

**Note**:

`importlib.reload` will not do the job, as it always "thoughtfully" updates the old module:

```
import importlib
import mymodule as m1
print(id(m1.func))
m2 = importlib.reload(m1)
print(id(m1.func))
print(id(m2.func))
```

Sample output:

```
139681606300944
139681606050680
139681606050680
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly I dont' think this solution allow me to have the same module loaded twice with the *same name* at different scope.

Comment: @Sisyphe You can simply bind it to the _same_ _local_ _name_.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a job for a context manager

```
import modul

def newfunc():
    print('newfunc')

class MyClass:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._f = modul.func
        modul.func = newfunc
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        modul.func = self._f

    def method(self):
        modul.func()


modul.func()
with MyClass() as obj:
    obj.method()
    modul.func()
modul.func()
```

outputs

```
func
newfunc
newfunc
func
```

where `modul.py` contains

```
def func():
    print('func')
```

**NOTE:** this solution suits single-threaded applications only (unspecified in the OP)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution works well, but only in a single threaded environment. The last entered object will always be the one who set the function globally. With two threads running their own context manager, the last opened will override the other's redefinition (correct me if I'm wrong). In this case, the override is reaching out of the scope.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution for a single-threaded application only. I made no mention of it since you had not specified such constraint. Edited.